# Showing a set is a $(k-1)$ dimensional manifold

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-topology

Let $A = \{(x_1, ..., x_k) \in \mathbb{R}^k : \sum _{i = 1} ^k x_i^{2i} = 1\}$. Show that $A$ is a $(k-1)$ dimensional manifold.

Definition of a patch: a set $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$ is a $d$ dimensional patch if it is homeomorphic to an open set in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Definition of a manifold: a set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$ is a $d$ dimensional manifold if there is an open covering $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ of $S$ such that $S \cap U_i$ is a $d$ dimensional patch for all $i\in I$.

My approach: I know that the sphere $S = \{(x_1, ..., x_k) \in \mathbb{R}^k : \sum _{i = 1} ^k x_i^2 = 1\}$ is a $(k-1)$ dimensional manifold. I think I can use the function $h: A \to S, h(x_1, ..., x_k) = (x_1^1, ..., x_k^k)$ somehow. I believe it is a homeomorphism to its image when restricted to $\{(x_1, ..., x_k) \in A : x_2, x_4, ... \ge 0\}$, but I don't know how to use this.

I'd like to get a hint to prove the first statement, and also to know if my approach can be continued.
Thanks.

Comment: That $A$ is a $(k-1)$-dimensional manifold follows from the Implicit Function Theorem. $A=g^{-1}\left(\left\{1\right\}\right)$ is the inverse of $\left\{1\right\}$ by the smooth map $g(x)=\sum_{i=1}^k x_i^{2i}$ where $1$ is a regular value of $g$, i.e., $\nabla g(x)\neq 0$ for all $x \in g^{-1}(\left\{1\right\})$.

Comment: @AugustoSantos thanks, but we didn’t get to the implicit function theorem yet. Is there another way?

Comment: Odd. The inverse and implicit function theorems are prerequisites for every discussion of smooth manifolds I’ve ever seen. But your course seems to be concerned only with topological manifolds.